# Calling WCF Service from JavaScript using AJAX through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf, service

I'm trying to call a WCF Service located locally through JavaScript. Here is a sample of the WCF Service.

```
public string GetMarkers()
    {
        List<Marker> lstMarkers = new MarkerMgr().GetMarkers().ToList();
        List<Marker> lstMark = new List<Marker>();
        foreach (Marker m in lstMarkers)
        {
            Marker marker = new Web_Service.Marker();
            marker.Id = m.Id;
            marker.Latitude = m.Latitude;
            marker.Longitude = m.Longitude;
            marker.Title = m.Title;
            marker.Description = m.Description;
            marker.Icon = m.Icon;
            lstMark.Add(marker);
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        jss.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

        return jss.Serialize(lstMark);
    }
```

and this is the function which I'm using to call the WCF Service.

```
function getMarkers() {
        var markers = null;
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:61892/Service.svc/GetMarkers", // the URL of the controller action method
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: true,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                markers = result;
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
        return markers;
    }
```

I've tried many different approaches to solve this but they weren't successful. From all the research I've done I think its something about the localhost. Anyone has an idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is that a cross domain request?

Comment: no its both the wcf service and the presentation are on localhost

Comment: then you may use relative path as url. No need for using ""http://localhost:61892/" in your url

Comment: I've tried it like this "url: "/Service.svc/GetMarkers" but the result is the same.. I think its something about the URL but I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: can you provide your page url, which calls the service?

Comment: Its also on localhost. "http://localhost:62256/Locations/Map"

Comment: its is not same domain. port is different.

Comment: Please include the detailed error information you are receiving in the question as well. Also place more details of the service itself: have you tried consuming it using a different method? Are you sure it is working at all?

Comment: There isn't a specific error given by the ajax error callback.. Yes I have tried both the ajax function and wcf service method and they both work.. I've access the wcf service from an MVC Controller and it worked. The problem is in the javascript URL

Comment: Actually by using the whole URL such as "http://localhost:61892/Service.svc/GetMarkers" its entering in the success function of the javascript but its returning null. even though I've set the return of the wcf service to a simple string.

Comment: Are you sure your WCF is running when you are running your web-application?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying for a cross domain ajax. So there shold enable cors in your ajax calling page.
And also server should make

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to "*"
```

take a look at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c412e600-0f4e-4a5b-8c45-bf77ed04f2a8)

Comment: I've tried that and still nothing.. The thing is that when I'm calling for the ajax the wcf service is not being called because I'm debugging in Visual Studio.. but when I invoke the method via the WCF Service it returns as its supposed to.